# how can i do test in react with jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

```
import React from 'react'
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import {ScreensLogin} from './Login'

test('render correctly', () => {
const state = {
    email: '',
    passwd: '',
    sendEmail: ''   
}
const props = {
    auth: {
        isAuth: false,
        error: false,
        isSigningin: false,
        emailSended: false
    },
    newPage: jest.fn()
}
const wrapper = shallow(<ScreensLogin {...props, ...state}/>)
expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

When i do test in react components, a component statefull, i need to pass state for component to do tests it or just props?

Comment: Depends on how the component works.

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on your intentions with tests. if you want just something simple to keep track of how your components look and some simple logic then you can continue with your current way of shallowing rendering and testing some combination of props.

The other way is to render the whole application where you can test like in a real browser and you can do more things as end users do. This one I usually prefer but it takes more time to run. This one will need JSDom as well. you can refer to https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html they have very well documented about all differences between shallow, render and mount

The rest method is to mount, mount is a little bit higher than shallow and simplier than render and you can use when you want to test componentdidmount.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assume the main question about passing state into component during testing.

Do you can do that? Yes, but in different way. Exactly as you do in *plain* React you cannot construct component(`shallow(<...>)` does that) passing state. Only props are going into play here. But there is a method [`.setState()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setState.html) so you can construct element and next line pass state in:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<ScreensLogin {...props}/>)
wrapper.setState(state);
```

Do you need that? I believe you don't. I'm sure you need to communicate with component under test exactly the same way you work with them in browser:

1. passing different props
2. calling props callbacks explicitly o0r implicitly(`wrapper.simulate('click', {/*event mock here*/})` does the same as `wrapper.props().onClick({/*event mocked*/})`)
3. checking `render()` result

Why do this way? 
1. setting `state` directly says nothing if it's possible to get such a state in the wild(say you may miss some state's property is used in `render` but never change by any of the methods)
2. it would be harder to keep tests actual: alongside any changes in components external interface(`props`) you need to align with it's internals(`state`)
3. and finally it would be easy to run into inconsistent state you would never get while interacting through `props`